# Present 2 navigationControllers in one stack in one go

Tags: ios, swift

current i am developing this app and i have the main and login screen.

The architecture works in such a way that when the app launches, the main screen will always present first.

then, if the user is not logged in, the login screen will be presented modally on top of the main screen. (i think this is a normal approach right?).

However, the thing is now that, whenever i do the following code.

```
self.present(mainNavigationController, animated: false, completion: {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginSignUp", bundle: nil)
            let loginNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginNavigationViewController") as! UINavigationController
            mainNavigationController.present(loginNavigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
```

I will always see a blank white main screen before the the login screen is shown, that is kinda ugly.. Anyone has any solution such that these two view controllers are stacked on top of each other from the very beginning and shown once, rather than shown in sequence?

Comment: Why don't you just set `mainNavigationController` as `rootViewController` and present `loginNavigationController ` in `ViewDidLoad` of `mainViewController`

Answer (score 0):

**You code is trying to accomplish this:**

1. Present main navigation controller modally over the current view controllers navigation.
2. Then after showing it present login modally on mainNavigation controller.

**You need to change in this way:**

1. Push your main screen in current navigation stack by pushViewController.
2. And then try to present login screen modally over the current navigation stack.